# Recursively Stepping through HTML DOM and printing Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, recursion

I'm trying to recursively step through the DOM for an HTML document and print the names of the nodes, while using indenting to identify child nodes. I modified a w3schools code example and ended up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test Example </title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the node names of the body element's child nodes.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction(document.documentElement)">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Whitespace inside elements is considered as #text, and text is considered as nodes.</p>

<!-- My personal comment goes here..  -->

<div><strong>Note:</strong> Comments in the document are considered as #comments, and comments are also considered as nodes.</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(node) {
indent = "";
txt = node.nodeName + "<br>";
document.write(txt);
var c = node.childNodes;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    myFunction(c[i], indent);
}    
}

function myFunction(node, indent) {
var indent = indent + "   ";
txt = indent + node.nodeName + "<br>";
document.write(txt);
var c = node.childNodes;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    txt = c[i].nodeName + "<br>"; 
    myFunction(c[i], indent);
}  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the result I get is:

```
undefined HTML
undefined HEAD
undefined #text
undefined TITLE
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined BODY
undefined #text
undefined P
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined BUTTON
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined P
undefined STRONG
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined #comment
undefined #text
undefined DIV
undefined STRONG
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined #text
undefined P
undefined #text
undefined SCRIPT
undefined #text
undefined #text
```

So I have a few questions
1) why is it not printing the indent value with the node name and instead printing `undefined`?
2) why is it printing the #text and #comments lines as well if I'm only asking for the nodes name?

I'm very new to HTML and javascript, so any insight would be helpful

**EDIT**

I fixed my second problem but I am still getting an issue with my first. My script now looks like

```
<script>
function myFunction(node) {
    var indent = "";
    txt = node.nodeName + "<br>";
    document.write(txt);
    var c = node.children;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        myFunction(c[i], indent);
    }    
}

function myFunction(node, indent) {
    indent = indent + "    ";
    txt = indent + node.nodeName + "<br>";
    txt = txt.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
    document.write(txt);
    var c = node.children;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        txt = c[i].nodeName + "<br>"; 
        myFunction(c[i], indent);
    }  
}

and my output looks like 

undefined    HTML
undefined        HEAD
undefined            TITLE
undefined        BODY
undefined            P
undefined            BUTTON
undefined            P
undefined                STRONG
undefined            DIV
undefined                STRONG
undefined            P
undefined            SCRIPT
```

I'm clearly still missing something but I don't understand what

**Edit 2**

Thanks to the help below I figured out my problem I was calling the wrong function inside the loop of the second myfunction (now called myfunction1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test Example </title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the node names of the body element's child nodes.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction(document.documentElement)">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Whitespace inside elements is considered as #text, and text is considered as nodes.</p>

<!-- My personal comment goes here..  -->

<div><strong>Note:</strong> Comments in the document are considered as #comments, and comments are also considered as nodes.</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(node) {
    var indent = "";
    var txt = node.nodeName + "<br>";
    document.write(txt);
    var c = node.children;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        myFunction1(c[i], indent);
    }    
}

function myFunction1(node, indent) {
    indent = indent + "      ";
    txt = indent + node.nodeName + "<br>";
    txt = txt.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
    document.write(txt);
    var c = node.children;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        txt = c[i].nodeName + "<br>"; 
        myFunction1(c[i], indent);
    }  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

now outputs

```
HTML
      HEAD
            TITLE
      BODY
            P
            BUTTON
            P
                  STRONG
            DIV
                  STRONG
            P
            SCRIPT
```

Comment: If you have an answer to your own problem, then post it as an answer, not an edit to the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) why is it not printing the indent value with the node name and instead printing `undefined`?

You have 2 functions of the same name, make sure you are running the correct one and supplying the correct arguments. From your updated output, you can use code like this to initialize `indent` to an empty string on first call.

```
function myFunction(node, indent) {
    indent = (indent || "") + "    ";
```

> 2) why is it printing the #text and #comments lines as well if I'm only asking for the nodes name?

Because these are nodes as well (and they have names), and you are not filtering them out in your code. Considering recursing through only elements, rather than all DOM nodes with `.children` instead of `.childNodes` if you want to exclude them.

Comment: Thanks! #2 fixed that issue and now my code prints the proper format. However I made the fix that #1 suggested but I'm still getting undefineds. I updated my question to include the changed code

Comment: @beelzabuddy you have two functions of the same name, please correct this in your question and show how you are calling it.

Comment: @beelzabuddy I've added code you can use to make the second argument optional.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I had originally called the second function myFunction1 but I wasn't calling that inside the loop of that function. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

> 1) why is it not printing the indent value with the node name and instead printing undefined?

You have two functions with the same name, which means the second is overwriting the first. Therefore, you're actually calling the second version and not passing anything to the `indent` param.

> 2) why is it printing the #text and #comments lines as well if I'm only asking for the nodes name?

Every node has a `.nodeName`, so you're getting the name of every node. If you only want Elements, then use an `if` statement, and check its `node.nodeType === 1`.